# Why don't Sass functions work outside selectors?

Tags: function, scope, sass, selector

I have an `example.scss` file.  When it is imported (parsed), I would like to push a value to a map.

```
// Declare selectors


register(example);
```

Prior to its import, the following has already been imported:

```
$example-map: (

);

@function register($key){
 $pointless: map-set($example-map, $key, true); // Have to assign to a variable
 @return true; // Have to return something
}
```

This is invalid as it appears that functions cannot be called outside of selectors. Why is this?

[Codepen here](http://sassmeister.com/gist/745a2a9a7742da180b54)

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  The correct answer to your question would be "because that's the way Sass was designed", but that wouldn't be very useful to you, now would it?

Comment: @cimmanon Interesting. Never heard of the XY Problem.

Comment: If I had to guess, it sounds like you're trying to create your own *import once* functionality.  Notice how I emphasized *import once*?  I bet that's a pretty good search phrase.

Comment: @cimmanon I'm familiar with LESS' `import-once` (also a Sass version [here](https://github.com/wilsonpage/sass-import-once)), but no, that isn't what I want to do. I want to push a value to a map when a settings file is loaded so that other files can then react to whether this settings file was imported. I appreciate that I could just set a Boolean flag, but that isn't what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mixin instead. Sure it's a little more to type but it should work.

Here's my quick test:

```
$register: ();

@mixin register ($key) {
  @if not index($register, $key) {
    $register: append($register, $key);
  }
}

@include register(foo);
@include register(bar);
@include register(bar);
@include register(baz);

body {
  content: $register;
}
```

Then you can test if it's registed just using `index`.

```
@if index($register, foo) {
  .foo {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Here's a small demo:

Sassmeister: http://sassmeister.com/gist/6069ebaba50d29052eeb